@Autowired not injecting repository in JavaFx FXML controller
I created a JavaFx project with Spring Boot integration. The project setup is created based on this tutorial: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/12/tutorial-reactive-spring-boot/. (the app starts and changes scenes correctly)
I am using Apache Derby as database.
I created logic to import data in database by reading excel file. This is working correctly.
The problem that I have is that I can't inject repository or service in the FXML controller so I can fetch data from the DB and populate a TableView.
This is my controller. Despite the @Autowired private RoutingRepository routingRepository I get this error: Cannot invoke "com.monbat.capacity.repositories.RoutingRepository.findAll()" because "this.routingRepository" is null.
package com.monbat.capacity.controllers;

import com.monbat.capacity.models.entities.Routing;
import com.monbat.capacity.repositories.RoutingRepository;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

@Component
@Controller
@Scope("prototype")
public class AllRoutingsController implements Initializable {
    @Autowired
    private RoutingRepository routingRepository;
    @FXML
    public TableView<Routing> routings_tbl;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        createColumns(Routing.class);
        setTableItems();
    }

    private void setTableItems() {
        List<Routing> routingsList =  this.routingRepository.findAll().stream().toList();
        ObservableList<Routing> routing = FXCollections.observableArrayList(routingsList);
        routings_tbl.setItems(routing);
    }

    private void createColumns(Class<?> dtoClass) {
        for (Field field : dtoClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            TableColumn<Routing, ?> column = new TableColumn<>(capitalize(field.getName()));
            column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(field.getName()));
            routings_tbl.getColumns().add(column);
        }
    }

    private String capitalize(String str) {
        if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
            return str;
        }
        return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
    }
}


Can you help me or give me some suggestions how to inject the repository or the service in the FXML controller so I can have access to the DB? I want to keep the Spring Boot integration because of the benefits it provides.
If you need to share more of my project let me know which part. I didn't want to flood this post with unnecessary code.
I tried with constructor injection but then I get error from the FXML fx:contructor which is looking for no args constructor.
Meanwhile I asked ChatGPT, Gemini and Copilot. And I tried all their suggestions but nothing worked for me.
I also check a lot of topics here but again nothing worked for me.

Please show repository class. And where findAll() called

This is the respository:
package com.monbat.capacity.repositories;
import com.monbat.capacity.models.dto.RoutingDto;
import com.monbat.capacity.models.entities.Routing;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface RoutingRepository extends JpaRepository<Routing, Long> {
}

You need to set the controller factory of the FXMLLoader to one that gets the controller instance from Spring. Some of these may be better duplicates: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javafx+fxml+controller+spring+dependency+injection

As an aside, I recommend making all @FXML-annotated fields private (they're typically implementation details). And in modern JavaFX, it's more typical to have an @FXML private void initialize() { ... } method instead of implementing the javafx.fxml.Initializable interface.

May be this helps? See https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/javafx-spring-boot/
Injecting the service

Now lets inject our new service into our existing controller. 
Its the usual Spring stuff, nothing special here.

@Component
@FxmlView("main-stage.fxml")
public class MyController {

    private WeatherService weatherService;
    @Autowired    
    public MyController(WeatherService weatherService) {
         this.weatherService = weatherService;    
    }
}




thank you very much for the reply. After implementing FxWeaver everything works correctly. But I have notes if someone has the same issue: in module-info.java open the controllers package to net.rgielen.fxweaver.core. I spent a few hour wondering why it can't open the FXML.
